# Adding a picture to a database using netbeans

Tags: java, database, image, netbeans, upload

Is there anyway to add an image to the database using Netbeans (Java)?

I want to first browse the image when we click on the choose file button, then it must add to the database when u click the "Add" button. Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 0):

To store your image in the database, CLOB or BLOB are type for the column holding the image in DB.
Netbeans in just and IDE you either need jsp( webpage) or java swing ( JFileChooser) which will accept image then you need to write java code to save the image in DB. Some of the links for reference.

In JSP to browse and select a file for upload you need a HTML  field in the form. As stated in the HTML specification you have to use the POST method and the enctype attribute of the form has to be set to "multipart/form-data".

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="imageName" name="imageName" />
    <input type="image" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

now this same this input i.e. InputStream in the DB

```
PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream(). 
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tablename (imageName, image) VALUES ( ?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, imageName);
preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(2, image);
```

If possible use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

EDIT: Added Swings code as per comments

EDIT :

As mentioned Swings are used so posting the code to help.

JFileChooser has a method, getSelectedFile(). Which is a File. You can

If you want to allow only .doc, .docx extensions set

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
 chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "word docs only", "doc", "docx");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

The save it as

 File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            String fileName = selectedFile.getCanonicalPath();
            if (!fileName.endsWith(EXTENSION)) {
                selectedFile = new File(fileName + EXTENSION);
            }
            ImageIO.write(image, FORMAT_NAME, selectedFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: The trouble is the "Add" button can't access the variables of "Choose file" button. I want to save the whole frame when the user clicks on the Add button. There are other fields like "employee name , id , address .... " in the frame. The "choose button" will find the path of the image , but the "add button" can't save the image to the database.

Comment: Post your code and screenshot..is this a JSP form or Swing based code?

Comment: It's a swing based code. 
The problem will get solved , if i could access the variables of "Choose file"(jButton1ActionPerformed) to "Add" button(jButton3ActionPerformed)
http://pastebin.com/Pq4kMSxc

Comment: I added the image.
 Now the problem is the image will be stored to the db when i click on the "Choose image" option. The image should store to the db only when a user clicks on the "Add" button .

Comment: You can use "save" dialog instead of an "open" dialog. chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG); updated the answer